# React Navigation Issue

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation 3 and I have 2 screens home and maps, in the maps screen i am getting the user current location as follow:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.getCurrrentLcation()

  }
  getCurrrentLcation (){
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        position => {
          const { coordinate, routeCoordinates, distanceTravelled } =   this.state;
          const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;

          const newCoordinate = {
            latitude,
            longitude
          };
           this.setState({
             latitude,
             longitude,
             routeCoordinates: routeCoordinates.concat([newCoordinate]),
             distanceTravelled:
             distanceTravelled + this.calcDistance(newCoordinate),
             prevLatLng: newCoordinate
           });
         },
         error => console.log(error),
         { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
      );
  }
```

when I navigate for the first time to the maps screen the getCurrentLocation func is being called and it works fine but when i press the back button and navigate to the maps screen again, it doesn't show the current location i think the getCurrentLocation is not being called.

App.js

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Maps: Maps,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

const Container= createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Container/>;
  }
}
```

HomeScreen.js

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.push('Maps')}>
                <Text>Go to Maps</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem isn't with the navigation, its because you are not clearing the watchID try adding the following

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **withNavigationFocus** API, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation-focus.html

And add this lifecycle to your class component

```
...
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.isFocused && !prevProps.isFocused) {
        // call your location function
        this.getCurrrentLcation()
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I think the issue is with the maps coz i tried alerting in getCurrentLocation func and the alert is working fine, it just the setState lat, long is not working